# if $\omega^n-1$ is a zero divisor in the ring R, then $\omega^{kn}-1$ is a zero divisor $\forall k\in \mathbb{N}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, complex-analysis

> Show that if $\omega^n-1$ is a zero divisor in the ring R, then $\omega^{kn}-1$ is a zero divisor $\forall k\in \mathbb{N}$. Show also that $\omega$ is a $2^q$-primitive root of unity if and only if $w^{2^{k-1}}=-1$.

Hi, I've tried the following: How $\omega^n-1$ is a zero divisor in R, $\exists b\in R-\lbrace0_R\rbrace$ such that $(\omega^n-1)b=0$. Now, we can decompose $\omega^{kn}-1$ of the form $(\omega^n-1)(\omega^{(k-1)n}+\omega^{(k-2)n}+\dots+\omega^2+\omega+1)$. Then $\omega^{kn}-1 | \omega^n-1$. Therefore $\omega^{kn}-1$ is a zero divisor $\forall k\in \mathbb{N}$. I'm right? How to do the other proof? Regards.

Edit: Show also that $\omega$ is a $2^q$-primitive root of unity if and only if $\omega^{2^{q-1}}=-1$.

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: The first step here probably ought to be to set $\zeta=\omega^n$ and forget about $\omega$ ...

Answer (score 1):

The proof is essentially good, with a glitch:
$$
\omega^{kn}-1=(\omega^n-1)({\dots})
$$
so $\omega^n-1$ divides $\omega^{kn}-1$ (not vice versa).

Anyway this is not important: if $b\ne0$ and $b(\omega^n-1)=0$, then also $b(\omega^{kn}-1)=b(\omega^n-1)({\dots})=0$.

For the second part, if $\omega^{2^{q-1}}=-1$, then $\omega^{2^q}=1$ and the multiplicative order of $\omega$ is $2k$, so the cyclic group generated by $\omega$ has $2^q$ elements, which are all $2^q$-th roots of unity.

The converse is similar: if $\omega$ is a primitive $2^q$-th root of unity, then $x=\omega^{2^{q-1}}$ satisfies $x^2=1$, so $x=1$ or $x=-1$. Can it be $x=1$?

Comment: Yes, sorry, is $w^{2^{q-1}}$.